# How to close the terminal without killing the jar file process that is running

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, javafx, terminal

I have created a .bat file that is included in the PATH variable so that when calling it from the terminal anywhere it would be executed and a java -jar command will be run.

```
@echo off
java -jar "[path]\[filename].jar"
```

This jar is a JavaFX Application which has a GUI interface.
But when I close the terminal, the JavaFX Application gets terminated.
Is there a certain command that could prevent the application from being killed when closing the terminal on windows?

Comment: It might help to know that on a Unix system the command you're looking for is called `nohup`.

Answer (score -2):

You use the below command

java -jar "[path][filename].jar" &

& symbol will run the process in background.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: Also tried this and it did not work